# Bug on integrating Material UI hooks and Apollo hooks

Tags: material-ui, apollo, next.js, react-hooks

When using Material UI hooks (as its [example shown here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs-hooks-with-typescript)) with NextJS and react-apollo-hooks, received bug -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'theme' of undefined
    at MyDocument.render (/material-ui/examples/nextjs-hooks-with-typescript/.next/server/static/development/pages/_document.js:156:38)
```

### Expected Behavior

Able to use Material UI hooks and Apollo hooks together.

### Current Behavior

`undefined` `pageContext` caused `TypeError: Cannot read property 'theme' of undefined` at line: 
https://github.com/ivawzh/material-ui/blob/fc6ae01e66bde4252a08903719a59ef108e05e5f/examples/nextjs-hooks-with-typescript/pages/_document.tsx#L14

[image]

### Steps to Reproduce

`This codesandbox.io template _may_ be a good starting point:
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/create-react-app

If you're using typescript a better starting point would be
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/create-react-app-with-typescript

If YOU DO NOT take time to provide a codesandbox.io reproduction, should the COMMUNITY take time to help you?`


-->

I have prepared a repo here https://github.com/ivawzh/material-ui/commit/fc6ae01e66bde4252a08903719a59ef108e05e5f

Steps:

1. `git clone git@github.com:ivawzh/material-ui.git`
2. `cd material-ui/examples/nextjs-hooks-with-typescript`
3. `npm install && npm run dev`
4. In web browser, open `http://localhost:3000/countries2`
5. See the error in your terminal

### Context

I am trying to use Apollo hooks with Material UI hooks example. 
From the repo above you will see the non-hook Apollo endpoint at `http://localhost:3000/countries` is working fine as expected. But when Apollo hooks is in used, app will crash because `pageContext` becomes undefined.

### Environment

https://github.com/ivawzh/material-ui/tree/fc6ae01e66bde4252a08903719a59ef108e05e5f/examples/nextjs-hooks-with-typescript

| Tech         | Version |
|--------------|---------|
| Material-UI  | v3.8.1  |
| React        |     16.7.0-alpha.2    |
| Browser      |    Chrome     |
| TypeScript   |     3.2.2    |
| react-apollo   |     2.3.3    |
| react-apollo-hooks  |     0.2.1   |

### Related Git issues

- https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/14140